# How do I find out why port 8172 is blocked?

Tags: windows, port, windows-firewall, telnet

We have some web sites hosted with a third-party company, and wish to use web deploy. They have told us that we need to ensure that port 8172 is open, as that is needed. As a test, they gave us a URL that uses that port, and said to try using telnet to connect.

We have tried using telnet, but it sites there for a while doing nothing, then reports "Connect to host lost". If we enter our IP address and this port number into http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ it confirms that the port is closed.

The set up here is simple, the PCs are connected to a Netgear N600 router, which plugs into the wall. Our ISP says they don't block any ports, so it seems to be either the PCs or the router. I had a look at the router web page, but couldn't see anything that indicated it blocked ports. However, Netgear's web site says their routers don't block any outgoing traffic by default, so the fact that it can't telnet out might rule out the router being the problem (but I could be way wrong here).

I looked through Windows Firewall, but couldn't see anything obvious (not that I really understand what I'm looking at). Following some instructions I [found here](https://www.howtogeek.com/220204/how-to-track-firewall-activity-with-the-windows-firewall-log/), I turned on firewall logging for the Domain, Private and Public profiles, and tried to telnet again. The log showed a few entries like this...

> 2017-05-11 16:30:20 DROP ICMP 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.22 - - 160 - - - - 5 1 - RECEIVE

...and then lots like this...

> 2017-05-11 20:02:28 DROP UDP 192.168.1.11 224.0.0.251 5353 5353 381 - - - - - - - RECEIVE
>   2017-05-11 20:02:28 DROP UDP 192.168.1.11 224.0.0.251 5353 5353 381 - - - - - - - RECEIVE
>   2017-05-11 20:02:28 DROP UDP fe80::5265:f3ff:fe01:7d10 ff02::fb 5353 5353 401 - - - - - - - RECEIVE

I don't see any reference to that port number in there, so I'm not sure this tells me anything.

Anyone able to help me? I need to open that port so I can telnet out. Please let me know if there is any more info I should give.

**UPDATE** - I'm now not sure this is the problem at all. Whilst trying to see if I could connect to the URL at all, I came across [this post](http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php/367205-How-do-i-do-a-trace-route-to-a-certain-port?s=cab73eb9ab491e64620bc11be15ad9ec&p=3469903&viewfull=1#post3469903), which suggested trying to use telnet to connect to gmail.google.com on port 443. Given that this port is (presumably) open on my machine, as I can use secure sites, this should work. However, I got the same problem as before, namely a few minutes pause, then the message "Connection to host lost." Anyone any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

One critical piece of information we lack here is what the network topology is beyond your server. I presume that you have something between where your network meets the ISP and your server (router, firewall, etc). Here are the things to check: one, is the port blocked at the firewall level? You may need to consult your network team if there is one for this question. If there is nothing blocking that port at the network level, the unit provided by your ISP may not be allowing the port in. (If you're in a small business with a cable hookup for example). Additionally, you can see the status of ports on a windows box with [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm no network expert (we don't have one, it's a very small office run from a spare room in the owner's house), so I'm not sure what to tell you. I've updated the question in case that helps. The ISP say they aren't blocking the port, but the router could be. I can't work out how to block/allow ports though

Comment: On the server open a command window and use `ipconfig` which will return a result like this:  
`Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:`

`Connection-specific DNS Suffix:`
`IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.12`
`Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0`
`Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1`  
Open a web browser and navigate to the default gateway address, then log in. From there you usually just need to add a rule to forward the port in question.

Comment: @princessovlce As I said in my updated reply, I can see the device web page, but can't see how to add a rule. I've posted a question on the NetGear forum, so will see what comes back. Thanks

Comment: Forgot to add that I tried CurrPorts, but it didn't show anything for that port.

Comment: I updated the question, as I'm now not sure if the port is the issue at all. Please can you see if you can explain what the problem might be

Comment: Can you follow the setup steps in this [wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Activate-Telnet-in-Windows-7) and tell us if you can connect using that process? Being able to use secure sites is totally different from being able to use ftp. If you can connect that way you should be able to connect to your external service. If not, google the user manual for that model unless your other post has been fruitful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup NAT in your netgear to that 8172 on the WAN interface gets forwarded to 8172 on your PC.